Replace previous NAs in previous column with non-NA value while keeping NAs that occur in later columns
In a data.table, I would like to fill forward previous NAs with the closest previous non-NA value, similar to this post
However, I would like to keep any NAs that occur after the non-NA value. The na.locf() function seems to replace the NA's afterwards. My data is an ontology map formatted so that the first column region_level1 is the top ancestor and subsequent columns are more specialised regions. Some ancestors can be divided into more children terms e.g. Cerebral cortex can be divided into Cerebral cortex 1 and Cerebral cortex 2, whilst Temporal cortex can not, which is why there are NAs in later columns as there are no existing child terms.
An example of what I'm trying to achieve:
Input data:
input_data <- data.frame(
  region_level1 = c("Brain", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  region_level2 = c(NA, "Grey Matter", NA, NA, NA, NA),
  region_level3 = c(NA, NA, "Cerebral Cortex", NA, NA, "Temporal Cortex"),
  region_level4 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Cerebral cortex 1", "Cerebral cortex 2", NA),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

 input_data
     region_level1          region_level2              region_level3                region_level4
1 Brain        <NA>            <NA>              <NA>
2  <NA> Grey Matter            <NA>              <NA>
3  <NA>        <NA> Cerebral Cortex              <NA>
4  <NA>        <NA>            <NA> Cerebral cortex 1
5  <NA>        <NA>            <NA> Cerebral cortex 2
6  <NA>        <NA> Temporal Cortex              <NA>

Desired output:
desired_output <- data.frame(
  region_level1 = c("Brain", "Brain", "Brain", "Brain", "Brain", "Brain"),
  region_level2 = c(NA, "Grey Matter", "Grey Matter", "Grey Matter", "Grey Matter", "Grey Matter"),
  region_level3 = c(NA, NA, "Cerebral Cortex", "Cerebral Cortex", "Cerebral Cortex", "Temporal Cortex"),
  region_level4 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Cerebral cortex 1", "Cerebral cortex 2", NA),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

desired_output
  region_level1    region_level2          region_level3              region_4               
1 Brain <NA>        <NA>            <NA>             
2 Brain Grey Matter <NA>            <NA>             
3 Brain Grey Matter Cerebral Cortex <NA>             
4 Brain Grey Matter Cerebral Cortex Cerebral cortex 1
5 Brain Grey Matter Cerebral Cortex Cerebral cortex 2
6 Brain Grey Matter Temporal Cortex NA

Using the na.locf() function:
converted_data <- zoo::zoo(original_data)
converted_data <- zoo::na.locf(converted_data)

converted_data
  region_level1    region_level2          region_level3              region_level4               
1 Brain <NA>        <NA>            <NA>             
2 Brain Grey Matter <NA>            <NA>             
3 Brain Grey Matter Cerebral Cortex <NA>             
4 Brain Grey Matter Cerebral Cortex Cerebral cortex 1
5 Brain Grey Matter Cerebral Cortex Cerebral cortex 2
6 Brain Grey Matter Temporal Cortex Cerebral cortex 2


Is there any way to preserve subsequent NAs?

Levia could you edit your question to include this more detailed information in the question itself (not the comments)? Most people will not thoroughly read the comments, and the question is quite confusing as written. The information you provided in the comments helps clarify (to some extent). Thank you!

@Levia if the posted answer is correct, I think you need to update the question. You said in your comment I want to preserve any NAs that occur to the right of a non-NA value, but replace NAs to the left with the ancestor terms. The current answer only looks at one column at a time, so not to the left or right. I've written a solution which does what I thought you were asking, but now I have no idea. Can you clarify?

Here is one option:
f <- \(x) {
  d = which(!is.na(x))
  if(length(d) == 1) x[d:length(x)] <- zoo::na.locf(x)
  if(length(d)>1) x[d[1]:(d[2]-1)] <- x[d[1]]
  return(x)
}

original_data[,lapply(.SD,f)]


Output:
       V1          V2              V3                V4
   <char>      <char>          <char>            <char>
1:  Brain        <NA>            <NA>              <NA>
2:  Brain Grey Matter            <NA>              <NA>
3:  Brain Grey Matter Cerebral Cortex              <NA>
4:  Brain Grey Matter Cerebral Cortex Cerebral cortex 1
5:  Brain Grey Matter Cerebral Cortex Cerebral cortex 2
6:  Brain Grey Matter Temporal Cortex              <NA>

Basically, f() is ingesting a vector (in this case, a column in your data.table), and identifying where non na occurs. If there is only one non-na value, then it simply replaces the values of x from that point on using zoo::na.locf(). If there is more than one non-na value, it replaces from the first to the next, with that first value. You don't actually need zoo::na.locf(x) in the first instance.. I.e. both if lines can end up assigning the value x[d[1]]

This is perfect, thank you so much! It works on my bigger dataset too

Here is an answer which does as described in your comment, i.e. preserves any NAs that occur to the right of a non-NA value, but replace NAs to the left with the ancestor terms.
Data
Let's create some simpler data.
input_data  <- data.table(
    a = c("Brain", NA, NA),
    b = c(NA, "Cortex", "Cortex"),
    c = c(NA, "Cortex 1", NA)
)
input_data
#         a      b        c
#    <char> <char>   <char>
# 1:  Brain   <NA>     <NA>
# 2:   <NA> Cortex Cortex 1
# 3:   <NA> Cortex     <NA>

# Replace NA that occurs to the left of non-NA
# but not to the right
desired_output  <- data.table(
    a = c("Brain", "Brain", "Brain"),
    b = c(NA, "Cortex", "Cortex"),
    c = c(NA, "Cortex 1", NA)
)
#         a      b        c
#    <char> <char>   <char>
# 1:  Brain   <NA>     <NA>
# 2:  Brain Cortex Cortex 1
# 3:  Brain Cortex     <NA>

Modify in place
We can create a set* function to modify in place. Essentially we do zoo::na.locf(). Then we run is.na() on a copy of the data.table shifted one column to the left, and look at which values are NA, and only replace NA values that occur to the left of a non-NA:
set_na_shift  <- function(dat) {

    do_replace  <- is.na(cbind(rep(NA, nrow(dat)), dat[,-ncol(dat), with = FALSE])) |>
        data.frame() |>
        setNames(names(dat))
    
    converted_data <- zoo::zoo(dat)
    converted_data <- zoo::na.locf(converted_data) |>
        data.frame()

    dat[, 
        (names(dat)) := lapply(names(.SD), \(nm) fifelse(
            do_replace[[nm]],
            converted_data[[nm]],
            dat[[nm]]
        )),
    .SDcols = names(dat)
    ]
}

Output
set_na_shift(input_data) # modifies in place, doesn't print
identical(input_data, desired_output) # TRUE


I've changed the title of my question, I'm really sorry about the confusion and thank you for your answer! I essentially wanted something that could look at a term, identify the ancestor (which would be the next non-NA value in the previous column), and replace the NA with that ancestor term and then identify the next ancestor etc. If the term has no children (i.e. there is no non-NA value in the right column, row below), the NA to the immediate right would be preserved. I hope this clears up any confusion!

@Levia is the expected output I included with this sample data correct? My answer produces different results to the other answer used on this data.

Apologies in the delay in replying. I've plugged your function into my example data and it works. However, with my actual data, I run into an issue where there is replacement of NAs at the wrong place when the ancestor term is divided into 3 or more children terms. This results in the most recent child term being duplicated for future NAs down the column. Do you have an idea how to remedy this? @SamR

Example input data: input_data <- data.table(     region_level1 = c("Brain", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),     region_level2 = c(NA, "Grey Matter", NA, NA, NA, NA,NA,"Frontal Lobe"),     region_level3 = c(NA, NA, "Cerebral Cortex", NA, NA, NA,"Temporal Cortex",NA),     region_level4 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Cerebral cortex 1", "Cerebral cortex 2", "Cerebral cortex 3",NA,NA),     stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
